# Retrieve a series knowing all its convergent infinite powersums

Tags: power-series, inverse, sumset

We would like to identify $s_n$ (non-increasing series) once we know, assuming are all of them convergent:

$$S_k=\sum_{n>=0}{s_n^k}$$

Known for all k values.

As example $\zeta(2k)$ should retrieve $1/{(n+1)^2}$
Another example $\frac{1}{1-a^k}$ should retrieve $a^n$

Comment: You won't get a unique characterization, as you can permute the terms and add as many 0s as you want.

Comment: ... and if you meant $S_k = \zeta(2k)$, you should get $s_n = (n+1)^{-2}$ (modulo the previous comment _at least_).

Comment: Noting @Andres comment I would add monotonically non-increasing requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the tempered distribution 
$T = \sum_{n \ge 0} \left( \delta_{s_n} - \delta_0 \right)$ where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta.  Its Fourier transform is
$$ f(t) = \sum_{n \ge 0} \left( \exp(-i t s_n)-1 \right) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-it)^k}{k!} S_k$$
assuming that converges absolutely.  In principle you should then be able to recover $T$, and thus the $s_n$, from $f$.